# How to set relationship between fields of imported CSV files in mongodb database

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-compass, import-csv

I have successfully imported a csv file into my mongodb database using mongodb `compass`, while importing the file, I had the choice to select/choose the data type of a field but when I try to change a field that is related to another collection to `ObjectId`, I got this error:

```
Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
```

so I had to leave the field as string even though the field is a relationship to another field in another collection within the same database. See the image bellow:

Click image to see larger view.
[image: Please click here to see the image]

from the image, the `olist_order_items_dataset` has a field `product_id` and `seller_id` which are in a relationship with `olist_products_dataset` and `olist_sellers_dataset` collections respectively but these fileds are imported as a strings rather than as an `ObjectId`. So the problem is how do I make the relationship between these fields?.

I have tried to change the fields to `ObjectId` within mongodb `compass` but I will have to do this for every document and I have 112, 650 documents in the collection.

Comment: You could "fix" the entire collection with one aggregation pipeline in `Compass` to `"$set"` the values to `ObjectId()` and then `"$merge"` the results back into the collection.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk the title you mean? it has been edited.

Comment: @rickhg12hs thank you for your answer, please is there any resources/links you can share to guide me on how I could achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within MongoDB `Compass` you can run `mongosh` (lower-left in GUI).

After `use leadDevAssignment` you could do something like:

```js
db.olist_order_items_datasets.update({
  "product_id": {"$type": "string"},
  "seller_id": {"$type": "string"}
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "product_id": {"$toObjectId": "$product_id"},
      "seller_id": {"$toObjectId": "$seller_id"}
    }
  }
],
{"multi": true}
)
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6uBKLdWqh-a).

Or, if you want to do it from the `Compass` Aggregation, you could do it like:

```js
db.olist_order_items_datasets.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "product_id": {"$type": "string"},
      "seller_id": {"$type": "string"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "product_id": {"$toObjectId": "$product_id"},
      "seller_id": {"$toObjectId": "$seller_id"}
    }
  },
  {"$merge": "olist_order_items_datasets"}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NcrV6zkHgCQ).